# Reference in callback function

Tags: javascript, tween

I'm trying to pass an object through a callback function `onUpdateTween( groups[i], this );` but it doesn't give me the correct object. It only gives me the last object from the groups array. How can I solve this?

```
function transform( duration ) {    
   for ( var i = 0; i < groups.length ; i ++ ) {                    

      new TWEEN.Tween(object.rotation)
      .to( rot , duration )
      .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut ) 
      .onUpdate( function() {
                   onUpdateTween( groups[i], this );
                 })
      .start();                 

   }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call a function in your loop:

```
function transform( duration ) {    
    for ( var i = 0; i < groups.length; i ++ ) {
        transformGroup( groups[i] );
    }

    function transformGroup( group ) {
        new TWEEN.Tween(object.rotation)
            .to( rot, duration )
            .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut ) 
            .onUpdate( function() {
                onUpdateTween( group, this );
            })
            .start();                 
    }    
}
```

Each time you call the `transformOne()` function, it creates a closure which holds the `group` parameter so the `onUpdate()` handler gets the correct group.

Or another way to do the same thing:

```
function transform( duration ) {    
    for ( var i = 0; i < groups.length; i ++ ) {
        transformGroup( groups[i], duration );
    }
}

function transformGroup( group, duration ) {
    new TWEEN.Tween(object.rotation)
        .to( rot, duration )
        .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut ) 
        .onUpdate( function() {
            onUpdateTween( group, this );
        })
        .start();                 
}
```

Either way would work just as well.

Is `this` getting the value you need there, or is that a problem too?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a local scope in order to encapsulate this variable :

```
function transform( duration ) {    
   for ( var i = 0; i < groups.length ; i ++ ) {                    

      new TWEEN.Tween(object.rotation)
          .to( rot , duration )
          .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut ) 
          .onUpdate( updateTween(i, this) )
          .start();                 

   }    
}

function updateTween(index, object) {
    return function() {
        onUpdateTween( groups[index], object );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function transform( duration ) {    
   for ( var i = 0; i < groups.length ; i ++ ) {                    
      with({i:i}) {
          new TWEEN.Tween(object.rotation)
          .to( rot , duration )
          .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut ) 
          .onUpdate( function() {
                       onUpdateTween( groups[i], this );
                     })
          .start();                 

       }
   }
}
```

:D

Comment: isn't `with` _nearly_ deprecated? it is at least forbidden with `strict mode` and not recommend to use.

Comment: @t.niese That's why the lulz. Well it is not deprecated, just not allowed in strict.